# How do I write a code that controls jumps, and creates a double jump action'?

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
# changed switch statement setup by creating a new variable and using "." operator
# removed extra delta in move_and_slide function
# left off attempting to add gravity to the game
# 2/26/2019
# removed FSM and will replace it with tutorial video code, for sake of completion

extends Node2D

const FLOOR = Vector2(0,-1)
const GRAVITY = 5
const DESCEND = 0.6
var speed = 100
var jump_height = -250
var motion = Vector2()

var jump_count = 0
var currentState = PlayerStates.STATE_RUNNING
var grounded = false

enum PlayerStates {STATE_RUNNING, STATE_JUMPING, STATE_DOUBLE_JUMPING, STATE_GLIDING}

func _ready():
    var currentState = PlayerStates.STATE_RUNNING
    pass

func jump():
    motion.y = jump_height

func glide():
    if motion.y < 500:
        motion.y += DESCEND

func _process(delta):
    var jump_pressed = Input.is_action_pressed('jump')
    var glide_pressed = Input.is_action_pressed('glide')
```

> *** the code below is where I attempted to count the jumps in order to keep them from surpassing two jumps. My goal is to create a double
>   jump and so I used the less than operator to control that number***
>           if jump_pressed:
>               if jump_count < 2:
>                   jump_count += 1
>                   jump()
>                   grounded = false <-- I had to copy paste this code again, below, so I don't get an error in my question.

```
    if jump_pressed:
        if jump_count < 2:
            jump_count += 1
            jump()
            grounded = false

    if grounded == false:
        if glide_pressed:
            glide()

    motion.x = speed

    motion.y += GRAVITY

    motion = move_and_slide(motion, FLOOR)

    if is_on_floor():
        grounded = true
        jump_count = 0
    else:
        grounded = false
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you need to use a `KinematicBody2D` and perform your logic in `_physics_process` if you would like to use `move_and_slide`, other than that, your code was almost working:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const FLOOR = Vector2(0,-1)
const GRAVITY = 3000
const DESCEND = 0.6

var speed = 100
var jump_height = 250
var motion = Vector2()

var jump_count = 0

func jump():
    motion.y = -jump_height

func glide():
    if motion.y < 500:
        motion.y += DESCEND

func _physics_process(delta):
    var jump_pressed = Input.is_action_pressed('jump')
    var glide_pressed = Input.is_action_pressed('glide')

    motion.y += delta * GRAVITY
    var target_speed = Vector2(speed, motion.y)

   if is_on_floor():
       jump_count = 0
       if glide_pressed:
           glide()        

    if jump_pressed and jump_count < 2:
        jump_count += 1
        jump()

    motion = lerp(motion, target_speed, 0.1)
    motion = move_and_slide(motion, FLOOR)
```

You also need to change the node type to KinematicBody2D in the Godot editor (right click on the node and then on change type).